# Add letters to string conditionally

Tags: python, regex

**Input**: `1 10 avenue`

**Desired Output**: `1 10th avenue`

As you can see above I have given an example of an input, as well as the desired output that I would like. Essentially I need to look for instances where there is a number followed by a certain pattern (avenue, street, etc). I have a list which contains all of the patterns and it's called `patterns`.

If that number does not have "th" after it, I would like to add "th". Simply adding "th" is fine, because other portions of my code will correct it to either "st", "nd", "rd" if necessary.

**Examples:**

`1 10th avenue` OK

`1 10 avenue` NOT OK, TH SHOULD BE ADDED!

I have implemented a working solution, which is this:

```
def Add_Th(address):
    try:
        address = address.split(' ')
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    for pattern in patterns:
        try:
            location = address.index(pattern) - 1
            number_location = address[location]
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            continue
        if 'th' not in number_location:
            new = number_location + 'th'
            address[location] = new
        address = ' '.join(address)

    return address
```

I would like to convert this implementation to **regex**, as this solution seems a bit messy to me, and occasionally causes some issues. I am not the best with regex, so if anyone could steer me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my current attempt at the regex implementation:

```
def add_th(address):

    find_num = re.compile(r'(?P<number>[\d]{1,2}(' + "|".join(patterns + ')(?P<following>.*)')
    check_th = find_num.search(address)

    if check_th is not None:
        if re.match(r'(th)', check_th.group('following')):
            return address
        else:
            # this is where I would add th. I know I should use re.sub, i'm just not too sure
            # how I would do it
    else:
        return address
```

I do not have a lot of experience with regex, so please let me know if any of the work I've done is incorrect, as well as what would be the best way to add "th" to the appropriate spot.

Thanks.

Comment: You should give it a try with regexs and then post if you have troubles. SO is not usually meant for writing code for you.

Comment: @FamousJameous Sure thing, I'll edit my question with what I currently have in terms of a regex solution. Thanks!

Comment: @FamousJameous I've updated my question.

Comment: What if you had 100 avenues? I don't see any word boundaries so you could match a lot more than just the actual word avenue

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In the last 3,400 addresses that I ran through my script I didn't have any inputs such as that. The answer posted below is working for me however there are some instances (such as 1000 broadway) that are causing issues.

Comment: That does not mean that you never will, also what about punctuation? Is there any punctuation in the strings like `10 street.`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm already stripping punctuation from the string. The odds of having an input such as "1000 avenue" are so slim that i'm okay with assuming that it won't happen.

Comment: How many patterns are you trying to match?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122148/discussion-between-harrison-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: This will do it without a regex http://pastebin.com/rHxBYzcc, it will not mach partial strings only exact matches.

Comment: What about `1st`  `2nd` `3rd` that do not have `th`?

Comment: @dawg, *Simply adding "th" is fine, because other portions of my code will correct it to either "st", "nd", "rd" if necessary.*

Comment: @dawg I have a portion of my code which will make those corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one way, finding the positions **behind a digit** and **ahead of one of those pattern words** and placing `'th'` into them:

```
>>> address = '1 10 avenue 3 33 street'
>>> patterns = ['avenue', 'street']
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\d)(?= ({}))'.format('|'.join(patterns)))
>>> pattern.sub('th', address)
'1 10th avenue 3 33th street'
```

Comment: I'm doing some tests with this and it seems to be doing what I need. Whoever down-voted this, could you explain why this wouldn't be an ideal solution?

Comment: I'm running into some issues with addresses such as "1000 broadway". It's adding th after 1000. What would be the best way to tell the code to not do this if certain phrases were present in the address. (Broadway isn't the only instance causing problems, there is a few more)

Comment: @Harrison What's wrong with "1000th broadway", and why do you include "broadway" in the patterns then? (I'm German, so expect me to not know the intricacies of this :-)

Comment: I was able to use your answer and build off of it to come to a functional solution. Thanks!